# php_register_variable_ex vulnerability question

Tags: php, buffer-overflow

Vulnerability I am referring to is:

http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/51830

And here in more detail:

http://auntitled.blogspot.com/2012/02/mini-poc-for-php-rce-cve-2012-0830.html

So basically what it amounts to is that in the code someone forgot to add an "else" statement and it allows an attacker-controlled string to be interpreted as a ZVAL struct. What I want to know is if an attacker could potentially store something else other than a hardcoded address in the string he/she controlls such as a pointer or register. I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but if it was it would make code execution much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nasty vulnerability.  In short,  it allows a **remote attacker** to read and/or write to an arbitrary memory address.  So you can't modify a register directly.  Being able to read an arbitrary memory address is very important in modern exploitation because it allows you to read an ASLR'ed memory address.  This is important because when you control the EIP,  you can then point it to the exact memory location of the attacker's shell code.  This vulnerability also bypasses canaries,  its not a buffer overflow, the attacker can overwrite the return address directly on the stack which will become the EIP when a target function returns.

Comment: Well I guess its not a traditional overflow but it is an overflow in that you can provide a greater number of variables than was intended that causes unintended behavior.

Comment: @user1424104  not really,  it feels more like a dangling pointer than a buffer overflow to me.  But its really neither,  its abusing PHP's own strange behavior.  This isn't the first ZVAL  struct vulnerability found by Stefan Esser.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "that excludes a pointer to a pointer"?  Presumably this vulnerability does allow to overwrite an address that happens to store another pointer.  Not sure if that's what you meant by "pointer to a pointer".

Comment: @D.W. well it won't automatically resolve an address,  yeah that was worded poorly.  Sorry.  Yeah you can overwrite an address no problem.